# Querying CloudKit Users Record gives "Can't query system types"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cloudkit

Okay, so I'm building a game on top of CloudKit and I want to query the users with the top 50 scores for a leaderboard.

```
// Create a CKQuery
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "score", ascending: false)
var query = CKQuery(recordType: "Users", predicate: predicate)
query.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

// Create a query operation
var queryOperation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
queryOperation.resultsLimit = 50
queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record: CKRecord!) -> Void in
    self.records.append(record)
}
queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor: CKQueryCursor!, error: NSError!) in
    // Log an error and show and alert
    if error != nil {
        println("Error querying for leaderboard: \(error)")
        var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Unable Donwload Leaderboard", message: "Unable to download the leaderboard at this time. Please try agin later.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        return
    }

    // Update the records array and refresh the table view
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

// Start the operation
database.addOperation(queryOperation)
```

This does not add any records to the records array and it comes back with this error in the completion block:

```
<CKError 0x1553cc10: "Permission Failure" (10/2007); server message = "Can't query system types"; uuid = 3349514B-02EC-40D7-B716-585D4ADD3128; container ID = "iCloud.com.MyCompany.MyApp">
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer to this one in Apple's docs. Specifically the docs on [CKQueries.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKQuery_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CKQuery/initWithRecordType:predicate:)

In the discussion for `initWithRecordType:predicate:` is says:

> You cannot query for user records and executing a query where the record type is set to CKRecordTypeUserRecord results in an error. You must fetch user records directly using their ID.

So I guess CloudKit doesn't let you query User records.

I ended up adding a score record with a reference to the users. I queried that and then I could get the users by their ID.

Comment: Shocking, that makes being able to store additional fields in the Users record completely useless! Should have known better as soon as seeing it breaking convention by being a plural there was going to be a nasty surprise.

Comment: I found a decent workaround to this. I created my own `User` table with all the fields I needed to be able to query on, and I include a `userRecordName` field that stores CloudKit's `recordName` that corresponds to what is stored in the default `Users` table.

Answer (score 2):

With your user CKRecordID you can get the record with

**CKDatabase fetchRecordWithID**

This way you can read the values like any other CKRecord.

Update:

Take a look to

**CKFetchRecordsOperation  fetchCurrentUserRecordOperation()**