# Cloudkit Query Error throw System Type error

Tags: cloudkit

I have been trying to query a cloudkit container having few fields under Record Types Users. After all the authentication it throws an error as Can't Query System Types. 
I am working on `Javascript` code and referring the Cloudkit catalog.
I am new to cloudkit and created few fields under Users and mark them as query-able also but not sure why getting such error. 
Any help.

[image: Link to Container View]

Answer (score 0):

CloudKit doesn't let you query the `Users` table to pull multiple records. You can only query by `recordName` (one at a time).

See this post for more details: [Querying CloudKit Users Record gives "Can't query system types"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27510024/querying-cloudkit-users-record-gives-cant-query-system-types)

As a workaround, I created my own `User` record type in the Public Database so I could make queries against it. It has worked pretty well so far.